# Error in publishing react website on IIS server [works in the local]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

I couldn't run the (asp.net) React.js site in one turn. First of all, I publish the site from Visual Studio to the httpdocs folder on the server. In the image below, you can see the file structure under httpdocs.

[image]

Then I set up the node.js as seen in the second picture attached. Here, I specified **service-worker.js** file as application startup file. But I'm not sure about that. Do you think these settings are correct?

[image]

Right now the site returns the error `ReferenceError: self is not defined`, the source of the error is service-worker.js. All the code works fine on my local computer. I think the error is about the way I configured the node.js. Any help_

Comment: You are going down the wrong path. You don't have a node.js application, you have static HTML files. (Unless Plesk added a feature for that, the closest thing would be configuring it as a PHP application.)

Comment: @CherryDT sorry for the confusion, it is a asp.net application. But, I am supposed to do node.js configuration since client side is done with react.js.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. React itself has nothing to do with node.js. Yes it normally uses node.js during development for building, serving and refreshing the app, but at the end of the day you get a regular static page with HTML, JS and CSS files and that's it. All you need is a way to host these files somewhere statically, no server-side code is required. (Unless you have an API but that's a different thing still not related to React.) The only server-side thing you may need is to configure your file server to redirect 404 errors to `index.html` so that client-side routing can work.

Comment: @CherryDT well this is what I was thinking. But then I was told that I need to pay for a virtual server since running React requires root access and some configurations on the server. I have no idea what those settings are supposed to be. I thought a shared plan would make it.

Comment: Yes a shared plan _will_ make it. There is no reason for root access at all. Any run-of-the-mill shared hosting plan (or a AWS S3 bucket which will cost you cents) will do. As I said in case you have a history-API-based client router (which is the default nowadays) there is one extra thing you need to do, and that is redirecting 404s to `index.html` - but in case of the usual shared hosting plans you can easily do that with a `.htaccess` file. (In case of S3 it's a simple configuration.)

Comment: Check this out: https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6 (Note, instead of `public_html` the folder may be called `httpdocs` or `htdocs` or `html` depending on your hosting provider.) - Or, for S3, this: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/host-your-react-app-on-aws-s3-with-ssl-2b58d62fd377

Comment: But, thinking about it again, you mentioned it's ASP.NET - I understand that as the _backend_ being ASP.NET, and for _that_ shared hosting won't help you. Yes the frontend can run in shared hosting just fine but you'd need to run your backend elsewhere, on IIS, but there you configure it as ASP.NET. node.js doesn't seem to have anything to do with neither your frontend nor your backend though, I think that was a red herring.